# Get date based on dayCount in java

Tags: java

I am using the below code to get date based on day count but its giving me the  wrong output it's giving 15-08 but should be 14-08

```
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("D", java.util.Locale.getDefault()).parse("227");
```

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

Java 8 and later comes with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

I expect that you want the year to be the current year as every 4 year you will have 1 shift since it include February the 29th.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofYearDay(today.getYear(), 227);
System.out.println("today: " + today + " date: " + date);
```

> today: 2016-01-22 date: 2016-08-14

Comment: Good answer. I would suggest passing a time zone (`ZoneId`) to the `now()` method. If omitted the JVM’s current default time zone is applied in determining today's date. That default can [change at any moment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-), even during runtime. Better to explicitly [specify the desired/expected time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Time zone is needed because the date is not the same around the world at any given moment, with a new day dawning earlier in the east.